# If there's query parameters after a user profile link, it won't onebox

Tags: bug, chat, user-accounts, onebox

I just pasted a user profile link into chat.

This works:

```
http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/77119/frew
```

This doesn't:

```
http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/77119/frew?tab=answers&sort=votes
```

Comment: I'd say that is by design. You are linking to a user *detail* page, not the main user info page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wasn't expecting it to link to the details page, I was expecting it to onebox and link to the main profile. dunno, maybe that's unreasonable.

Comment: But if I wanted to link directly to someones questions or answers or reputation tab, or any of the other detail views, I would **not** want it one-boxed and linked to the main profile, no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters true. like I said, I don't know if this is a reasonable request or not. we'll see what SE thinks, I guess